# How to use a variable in LXML XPath Expression

Tags: python, xpath, python-3.x, lxml

I'm using Python 3.3 in eclipse with PyDev plugin on Windows 7.

I need to parse an XML file using XPath and LXML. If I use a static XPath expression it works but I need to use a variable one but when I use a variable in the expression it doesn't work.

If I use this code:

```
xml = etree.parse(fullpath).getroot()
tree = etree.ElementTree(xml)

nsmap = {'xis' : 'http://www.xchanging.com/ACORD4ALLEDI/1',
         'ns' : 'http://www.ACORD.org/standards/Jv-Ins-Reinsurance/1' }

p = tree.xpath('//xis:Line', namespaces=nsmap)
print (p)
for e in p:
    print(e.tag, e.text)
```

it works as I want, the `print(p)` returns

```
 [<Element {http://www.xchanging.com/ACORD4ALLEDI/1}LloydsProcessingCode at 0x2730350>]
```

but if I change it to:

```
xml = etree.parse(fullpath).getroot()
tree = etree.ElementTree(xml)

nsmap = {'xis' : 'http://www.xchanging.com/ACORD4ALLEDI/1',
         'ns' : 'http://www.ACORD.org/standards/Jv-Ins-Reinsurance/1' }
header = 'Jv-Ins-Reinsurance'
ns = 'xis:'
path = "'//" + ns + header + "'"    
p = tree.xpath('%s' % path, namespaces=nsmap)
print ('p = %s' % p)
for e in p:
    print(e.tag, e.text)
```

the `print(p)` returns:

```
p = //xis:Jv-Ins-Reinsurance
```

and I get an error:`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag'`.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to remove the single quotes ? I think you have one level too much of quoting in your `path` variable. I would just use `path = "//" + ns + header`.

Comment: Because it seems EASIER TO DEBUG, I like the general, string building, approach of this solution better than the approach i found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285816/lxml-html-parsing-with-xpath-and-variables

Answer (score 0):

You are building a string *with literal quotes*. You don't need to, omit the `'` characters.

```
path = "//" + ns + header
p = tree.xpath(path, namespaces=nsmap)
```

or use string formatting:

```
path = "//{}{}".format(ns, header)
p = tree.xpath(path, namespaces=nsmap)
```

Your original version was the equivalent of:

```
path = "'//xis:Jv-Ins-Reinsurance'"
```

(note the extra single quote characters).