# No nested nodes. How to get one piece of information and then to get additional info respectively?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

For the code below I need to get dates and their times+hrefs+formats+...(not shown) respectively.

```
<div class="showtimes">
    <h2>The Little Prince</h2>

    <div class="poster" data-poster-url="http://www.test.com">
        <img src="http://www.test.com">
    </div>

    <div class="showstimes">

        <div class="date">9 December, Wednesday</div>
        <span class="show-time techno-3d">
            <a href="http://www.test.com" class="link">12:30</a>
            <span class="show-format">3D</span>
        </span>

        <span class="show-time techno-3d">
            <a href="http://www.test.com" class="link">15:30</a>
            <span class="show-format">3D</span>
        </span>

        <span class="show-time techno-3d">
            <a href="http://www.test.com" class="link">18:30</a>
            <span class="show-format">3D</span>
        </span>


        <div class="date">10 December, Thursday</div>
        <span class="show-time techno-2d">
            <a href="http://www.test.com" class="link">12:30</a>
            <span class="show-format">2D</span>         
        </span>

        <span class="show-time techno-3d">
            <a href="http://www.test.com" class="link">15:30</a>
            <span class="show-format">3D</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

To do this, I use this code (python).

```
for dates in movie.xpath('.//div[@class="showstimes"]/div[@class="date"]'):
    date = dates.xpath('.//text()')[0]

    # for times in dates.xpath('//following-sibling::span[1 = count(preceding-sibling::div[1] | (.//div[@class="date"])[1])]'):
    # for times in dates.xpath('//following-sibling::span[contains(@class,"show-time")]'):
    # for times in dates.xpath('.//../span[contains(@class,"show-time")]'):
    # for times in dates.xpath('//following-sibling::span[preceding-sibling::div[1][.="date"]]'):
        time = times.xpath('.//a/text()')[0]
        url = times.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
        format_type = times.xpath('.//span[@class="show-format"]/text()')[0]
```

To get dates is not a problem, but I have a problem how to get the rest info for particular date  respectively. Tried many different  ways - no luck (in comments some of them). I can't find the way how to deal with the case when the nodes that I need are one under another (on the same level?). In this case:

```
-> div Date1
-> span Time1
-> span href1
-> span Format1

-> span Time2
-> span href2
-> span Format2

-> span Time3
-> span href3
-> span Format3

-> div Date2
-> span Time1
-> span href1
-> span Format1
# etc etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `lxml` support referencing python variable from XPath expression, which proven to be useful for this case i.e for every `div date`, you can get the following sibling `span` which the nearest preceding sibling `div date` is the current `div date`, where reference to the current `div date` is *stored in python variable* `dates` :

```
for dates in movie.xpath('.//div[@class="showstimes"]/div[@class="date"]'):
    date = dates.xpath('normalize-space()')
    for times in dates.xpath('following-sibling::span[preceding-sibling::div[1]=$current]', current=dates):
        time = times.xpath('a/text()')[0]
        url = times.xpath('a/@href')[0]
        format_type = times.xpath('span/text()')[0]
        print date, time, url, format_type
```

**output :**

```
'9 December, Wednesday', '12:30', 'http://www.test.com', '3D'
'9 December, Wednesday', '15:30', 'http://www.test.com', '3D'
'9 December, Wednesday', '18:30', 'http://www.test.com', '3D'
'10 December, Thursday', '12:30', 'http://www.test.com', '2D'
'10 December, Thursday', '15:30', 'http://www.test.com', '3D'
```

References :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17750629/2998271
- http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method

Comment: Didn't know about variable feature in lxml. Thanks!

Comment: Neither did I, I was just lucky to find out about it. And you're welcome :)